# Run Social Engine 4.8.7 with the php built-in server

Tags: php, webserver, socialengine

Social Engine version **4.8.6** (fresh installation), if I lunch:

```
$ php -S localhost:9299 
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 Development Server started at Wed Jul 29 12:39:16 2015
Listening on http://localhost:9299
Document root is /tmp/aa/486
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:46 2015] 127.0.0.1:48641 [302]: /
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:47 2015] 127.0.0.1:48642 [302]: /index.php
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:49 2015] 127.0.0.1:48645 [200]: /index.php/members/home
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:52 2015] 127.0.0.1:48650 [200]: /application/css.php?request=application/themes/modern/theme.css&c=1
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:52 2015] 127.0.0.1:48654 [200]: /externals/chootools/chootools.js?c=1
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:52 2015] 127.0.0.1:48651 [200]: /externals/mootools/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat-yc.js?c=1
[Wed Jul 29 12:39:52 2015] 127.0.0.1:48652 [200]: /externals/mootools/mootools-more-1.4.0.1-full-compat-yc.js?c=1

...
**Ok the web server is serving the application**
...
```

from root path, **it works** and the php built-file server serve the entire application.

Social Engine version **4.8.7** (fresh installation), if I lunch:

```
$ php -S localhost:9292
```

from root path, it not works and the php built-file server **does not serve the entire application**.
This is the output by php built-in server:

```
$ php -S localhost:9292 
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 Development Server started at Wed Jul 29 11:56:34 2015
Listening on http://localhost:9292
Document root is /tmp
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Jul 29 11:56:38 2015] 127.0.0.1:46849 [302]: /
[Wed Jul 29 11:56:39 2015] 127.0.0.1:46850 [302]: /index.php
**Not works. The web server is blocked here**
```

**I have try with fresh installation, so you can easily reproduce the error.**

Why with Social Engine **4.8.7** the php built-in server not works?! I have look the change log but is not useful.

I have open an issue here: 
https://github.com/SocialEngine/phpv4-issues/issues/213